# Codeiniter: Multiple file input field is not working

Tags: file, codeigniter

I have multiple file upload fields but it is uploading file from one field only.

First field

```
if (!empty($_FILES['aadhar_image']['name'])) {
            $config['upload_path'] = "./public/images/user/";
            $config['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|docx|dotx";
            $config['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $aadhar_image = date('hisdmy').rand();
            $config['file_name'] = $aadhar_image;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('aadhar_image');
        }
```

Second field

```
if (!empty($_FILES['pan_image']['name'])) {
            $config2['upload_path'] = "./public/images/user/";
            $config2['allowed_types'] = "gif|jpg|png|jpeg|pdf|docx|dotx";
            $config2['overwrite'] = TRUE;
            $pan_image = date('hisdmy').rand();
            $config2['file_name'] = $pan_image;
            $this->load->library('upload', $config2);
            $this->upload->do_upload('pan_image');
        }
```

and so on..

it upload file from first field only, and ignores rest of the field.

> UPDATE

After doing some more testing I found that it is using same name on file to upload in folder. Means, name which is created on first `if`  condition is being used for all remaining `if` conditions, but different name given in each if condition but still it is picking name only from first `if` conditions.

I tried to use `unset` function between `if` conditions too but it didn't work. I used `unset($config['file_name']);` And also tried `unset($config=);` but failed

> update

html

```
<form id="wrapped2" action="" method="post" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <label>Upload Addhar Card</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="aadhar_image" class="form-control required">
        </div>
 </div>

<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
      <label>Upload Pan Card</label>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="file" name="pan_image" class="form-control required">
        </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: share your html code also

Comment: @umefarooq Updated

Comment: please show form tag also not just input fields

Comment: @umefarooq Code updated

Comment: try this if condition if($_FILES['filed_name']['error'] == 0) will work for you.

Comment: @Rishabh where is your form action or you send it by ajax?

Comment: @umefarooq I tried error displaying but it came empty. May be it was picking error from first `if ` condition.

Comment: @KUMAR Emtpy action will result in submitting form on same page. And all data (texts and ) submitted successfully in db.

Comment: you write view code & controller code in same page how is it possible??

Answer (score 0):

You can upload files using

```
$upload_dir = "public/images/user/";
$allowed_file_type = array('gif', 'png', 'jpg');

    if ($_FILES['aadhar_image']['name'] != "") {
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["aadhar_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_file_type )) {
            echo 'file type not allowed'; //you can add error as per your coding standard 
        }else{
            $file = md5(uniqid($_FILES["aadhar_image"]["name"], true));
            $file .= "." . $ext;
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["aadhar_image"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir . $file);
        }
    }

    if ($_FILES['pan_image']['name'] != "") {
        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES["pan_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        if (!in_array($ext, $allowed_file_type )) {
            echo 'file type not allowed'; //you can add error as per your coding standard 
        }else{
            $file1 = md5(uniqid($_FILES["pan_image"]["name"], true));
            $file1 .= "." . pathinfo($_FILES["pan_image"]["name"], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
             move_uploaded_file($_FILES["pan_image"]["tmp_name"], $output_dir . $file1);
        }
    }
```